# How to avoid backslash coming from inner cat cmd in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am facing issue with shell script. I am trying to read available environment variables(passed by user) and if present, I want to append them to below cmd this cmd -->  `terraform plan`
To implement this, I am reading all known input variables and prepare a string which look like this --> `'-var="db_ebs_volume_size=16" -var="db_dns_ttl=9999" '`
Then echo the contain of variable into a file using this cmd --> `echo $temp > temp.txt`
Then trying to execute this overall cmd which is getting fail with below error:

```
terraform plan $(cat temp.txt)
```

Error:-

```
│ Error: Value for undeclared variable
│
│ A variable named "\"db_dns_ttl" was assigned on the command line, but the
│ root module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value,
│ add a "variable" block to the configuration.
╵
╷
│ Error: Value for undeclared variable
│
│ A variable named "\"db_ebs_volume_size" was assigned on the command line,
│ but the root module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this
│ value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.
```

I don't know why output of inner cmd contain backslash () before double quote which is causing issue here.
If I try to run this cmd, it work fine: `terraform plan -var="db_ebs_volume_size=16" -var="db_dns_ttl=9999"`

I also try to use but still seeing same error `"$(cat temp_cmd.txt |sed 's/\\\{1\}/\\\\/g' )"`

Can anyone help me how to avoid this backslash before double-quote so that it return desired string and full can work.

Comment: When you generate `'-var="db_ebs_volume_size=16" -var="db_dns_ttl=9999" '`, try NOT generate double quotes `"`.

Comment: what is output of `cat temp.txt` ?

Comment: I need to use double-quote in temp.txt. The output of temp.txt is -var="db_ebs_volume_size=16" -var="db_dns_ttl=9999"

Comment: @AshishSharma Have you tried creating `temp.txt` without the double quotes? What happens when you do?

Comment: That way it will work. But I need double quote in the full cmd terraform plan....

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** don't store the double-quotes in `temp.txt`

**Slightly longer answer:** store variables in a[`.tfvars` file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) and use `-var-file` instead

---

**Explanation:**

Quoting is used to allow the shell to parse input:

```sh
$ a="1 2 3  4 5"
$ echo "[$a]"
[1 2 3  4 5]

$ b='"1 2  3 4 5"'
$ echo "[$b]"
["1 2  3 4 5"]
```

In the first case above, the double-quotes are used to protect the whitespace.

In the second case, the outer single-quotes protect the whitespace and the double-quotes are considered to be part of the value itself.

When you do `$(cat temp.txt)`, the shell considers everything returned by cat to be part of the value - including the double-quotes:

```
$ echo "a" > f
$ cat f
a
$ v=$(cat f)
$ echo "[$v]"
[a]

$ echo '"b"' > f
$ cat f
"b"
$ v=$(cat f)
$ echo "[$v]"
["b"]
```

When you run your command directly:

```
terraform plan -var="db_ebs_volume_size=16" -var="db_dns_ttl=9999"
```

the shell parses the line into:

- program: `terraform`
- argument 1: `plan`
- argument 2: `-var=db_ebs_volume_size=16`
- argument 3: `-var=db_dns_ttl=9999`

It invokes `terraform` and passes it the three arguments.

When the `terraform` program looks at argument 2, it parses it into:

- command: `-var`
- the first `=` tells it to expect a name=value pair
- name: `db_ebs_volume_size`
- the second `=` indicates end of name / start of value
- value: `16`

When you run:

```
terraform plan $(cat temp.txt)
```

the shell first obtains the value of `cat temp.txt`, then splits it on whitespace, and produces:

- program: `terraform`
- argument 1: `plan`
- argument 2: `-var="db_ebs_volume_size=16"`
- argument 3: `-var="db_dns_ttl=9999"`

When `terraform` runs it parses argument 2 as:

- command: `-var`
- the first `=` tells it to expect a name=value pair
- name: `"db_ebs_volume_size`
- the second `=` indicates end of name / start of value
- value: `16"`

---

So, to get your code to work, don't store the double-quotes - they aren't needed:

```
$ cat temp.txt
-var=db_ebs_volume_size=16 -var=db_dns_ttl=9999
```

Even better, sidestep the shell-parsing issues entirely by storing the variables in a `.tfvars` file and loading with `-var-file`:

```
$ cat my.tfvars
db_ebs_volume_size = 16
db_dns_ttl = 9999

$ terraform plan -var-file=my.tfvars
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It clears some of my doubt. But my point is actually what over all cmd get converted to is :  terraform plan -var=\"db_ebs_volume_size=16\" -var=\"db_dns_ttl=9999\"

This is the issue here. What I wanted is : terraform plan -var="db_ebs_volume_size=16" -var="db_dns_ttl=9999"

This is syntax of terraform cmd when we need to pass env-variables then I need to enclose key=value in double quote. For detail check here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. As I attempted to explain in the answer, the double-quotes are removed by the shell before terraform ever sees them (when run directly). That is why there is a problem when terraform actually sees them (when arguments added from cat).

Comment: Notice that the second example from your link uses single quotes, not double quotes - the quotes are for the benefit of the shell, not terraform. When you store the arguments in your temp file, the shell only splits on whitespace, it doesn't try to parse the quotes, brackets, etc.

Comment: As your links states, the preferred approach (to avoid all of the shell parsing issues), is to [store the variables in a `.tfvars`file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html#input-variables-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using printf instead of echo? There's a few advantages using printf in bash script. I run into issues with line endings comming from echo on bash.

Comment: I am using cat not echo. terraform plan $(cat temp.txt)